# Load a Specific Collection as a Shpoify Related Products

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to load product accessories when an end user looks at a one of my product pages. I have figured out how to exclude collections from displaying, 
but I am unsure how to set the 'liquid' to call one collection specifically.

```
{% assign number_of_related_products_to_show = 12 %}

{% assign number_of_related_products_to_fetch = number_of_related_products_to_show | plus: 1 %}
{% assign exclusions = 'frontpage,all,dual_camera,single_camera,series_dr650s,series_dr400_series' | split: ',' %}

    {% if collection == null or collection.handle == 'frontpage' or collection.handle == 'all' %}
        {% assign found_a_collection = false %}
        {% for c in product.collections %}
            {% if collection and collection.all_products_count > 1 %}
                {% unless exclusions contains collection.handle %}
                    {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
                    {% assign collection = c %}
                {% endunless %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% if collection and collection.products_count > 1 %}
<div class="h_row_4 animated  fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <h3>{{ 'products.general.related_products' | t }}</h3>
    {% assign current_product = product %}
    {% assign current_product_found = false %}
  </div>
  <div class="carosel product_c">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div id="featured-products-section-{{ section.id }}" class="owl-carousel">
        {% for product in collection.products limit: number_of_related_products_to_fetch %}
        {% if product.handle == current_product.handle %}
        {% assign current_product_found = true %}
        {% else %}
        {% unless current_product_found == false and forloop.last %}
        {% include 'product-loop' %}
        {% endunless %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a specific collection:
{% for product in collections[handle-of-the-collection-you-want].products %}
Do something
{% endfor %}

Comment: So I can "chain or link" objects in this programming language. Similar to jQuery?

Comment: Not everytime, it depends on Liquid objects. You may access directly to a specific collection, product or page objects using this syntax collections[handle].description for example.